# Unity - TextMeshPro text object doesn't update

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have been using TMP objects in several instances in my game, but all of a sudden it decides not to work on a certain object.

```
public class BeforeRoundTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI timer;
    private Timer oneSecondTimer;
    private int time = 5;

    public void StartCountdown()
    {
        Debug.Log("One second timer");
        oneSecondTimer = new Timer(1000);
        oneSecondTimer.Elapsed += UpdateTime;
        oneSecondTimer.Enabled = true;
        oneSecondTimer.AutoReset = true;
        oneSecondTimer.Start();
    }
    private void UpdateTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(time == 0)
        {
            oneSecondTimer.Stop();
            return;
        }
        timer.text = $"{time}";
        time--;
    }
}
```

I know the text is updating because I put debug statements (I have since removed them) and they fired when UpdateTime() is called. I also viewed the inspector when the game was playing, and the text value would update in front of my eyes. The text only changes when I make some stylistic change to it (i.e. making it bold, changing the font asset, including changing the text itself). I have looked back to my old code and it basically runs the exact same way, but it actually changes in game.

Comment: There is obviously nothing wrong with the timer.text = `interpolated string` that I can see. Are you sure the code gets around the first conditional with the return?

Comment: @TEEBQNE yes, it all executes just fine. No errors, it even changes the value in the inspector. The only problem is that the TextMeshProUGUI element doesn't update

Comment: Interesting. Can you try the line `timer. ForceMeshUpdate(true)` right under it? Have you also tried setting your text not using the interpolated string? So instead of `timer.text = $"{time}";` just setting `timer.text = timer.toString();`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after taking a break, I decided to find another way to call my method every second. Instead of using a Timer, I decided to use Unity's InvokeRepeating() function.

```
public class BeforeRoundTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI timer;
    private int count = 0;

    public void StartCountdown()
    {
        InvokeRepeating(nameof(UpdateTime), 0, 1f);
    }
    private void UpdateTime()
    {
        if(count == 5)
        {
            CancelInvoke("UpdateTime");
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log("Update Time");
        timer.text = $"{5 - count}";
        count++;
    }
}
```

One thing I noticed when trying to use the Timer in a different way is that it was only updating the text value every other second. It ran 10 times (I put a Debug.Log() in UpdateTime()) but only changed the value every other time while not actually updating the TMP. You could replace `nameof(UpdateTime)` with `"UpdateTime"`, but Visual Studio recommended that I use the former so I went with that.

In short: don't use timers, use Unity's InvokeRepeating() function because it works perfectly. It is actually very similar to JavaScript's setInterval() which I found interesting.